# Django: Saving an image file from a form

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I want to save the image which as been uploaded via the PaletteGenForm as such:

```
#Form 
class PaletteGenForm(forms.Form):
    im = forms.ImageField(required=True)

#View
def palette_gen_view(request):
    PATH_OF_IMAGE_TO_BE_PALETTED= MEDIA_ROOT+ "/tobesaved.png"
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PaletteGenForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            im = Image.open(StringIO(request.FILES['im']['content']))
            im.save(PATH_OF_IMAGE_TO_BE_PALETTED, "PNG")
            #call some functions to generate pallete
            return #returns the palette of the image.
    else:
        form = PaletteGenForm()
    return render_to_response('palette_generate.html', {'form': form,})
```

However here is my error when calling this URL:

```
'InMemoryUploadedFile' object is unsubscriptable
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
im = Image.open(StringIO(request.FILES['im'].read()))
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, here is what I get after changing to yours:

TypeError at /palet/

'module' object is not callable

Comment: looks like you are having 'import StringIO' in your code instead of 'from StringIO import StringIO'.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure you need to wrap it in a StringIO at all. Try

```
im = Image.open(request.FILES['im']['content'])
```

Comment: without wrapping I still get the same error:


TypeError at /palet/
'InMemoryUploadedFile' object is unsubscriptable

Answer (score 0):

try reading the data from form cleaned_data

```
im = Image.open(StringIO(form.cleaned_data['im'].read()))
```

for me this worked (didn't tried reading from the request)

Comment: this is same as Alexander Artemenko answer,
can you provide the complete traceback to see which line is giving the error: TypeError at /palet/ 'module' object is not callable